# Firefox: How do I perform "Move to New Popup Window" on a tab?

Tags: firefox, javascript, window, popups, web-application

Firefox has a tab bar context menu item "Move to New Window". This will create a new window with all the default window configuration, incl. vertical tabs, location bar and whatever else one might have.

I occasionally want to move a web application from regular tab into an "app"-like window, i.e. [all the window.open features removed](https://superuser.com/questions/91052/howto-open-new-firefox-window-without-toolbars-tabs-addins-etc-shortcut-rat). Also known as a popup.

Sounds like an addon, but I'm not finding any so far.

Any other tricks or suggestions in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

Building an answer here. This probably goes into the territory of pinned tabs. Couple of addons out there, that take a shot at this, but none of them want to hide the tabbar.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simply-pinned/?src=search

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/aaapptabs/?src=search

EDIT kind of sucks that [Chrome application shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95710?hl=en) are the closest thing to a solution. If only links could still be opened in Firefox..

Answer (score 0):

Found this https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/popvideo/ but only for video.